# How can I remove all namespaces from a SOAP payload created by a JAX-WS class?

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb, jax-ws

I have many classes generated from a WSDL by [Axis](https://axis.apache.org/axis/java/ant/axis-wsdl2java.html). This includes service calls that look similar to this: `ServiceClientClass.getClientSoap().methodName(args..., JAXB structure)`. This generates a request and "works" -- it creates namespaces that *should* work, and connects to the remote server. However, the parser on the remote end seems to expect a completely unnamespaced document. I am aware that is bad behavior, but I don't control the remote point.

How can I completely remove all namespaces from this payload? The generated client classes currently live in a JAR file, so if I can avoid modifying those, that would be preferable.